# Object not moving towards other object position correctly - Vector3.MoveTowards

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, move

I'm trying to make transform position of `instance` move towards transform position of gameobject `PointCopy` , which is in the scene.

Problem: what this code does is flick `instance` to `PointCopy` for like a split second, and then go back to its own original position. How do I get it to smoothly move `instance` towards `PointCopy` position and stay in place there after it has finished moving?

Here is the code that spawns `instance`. It is placed on an empty gameobject in the scene called 'SpawnToLerp'.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawntoLerp : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject CubePrefab;
    public GameObject instance;
    public PointCopy PointCopy; //i want to move instance position to PointCopy position


    void Start()
    {
      instance = Instantiate(CubePrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation) as GameObject;
    }


    void Update()
    {
        instance.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards
        (transform.position, PointCopy.transform.position, 5f * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

The code for PointCopy is blank, or default.
I found that if I put code `public Transform transform;` in `PointCopy.cs` at the top, the result was the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `transform.position` by `instance.transform.position` in

```
 instance.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards
    (transform.position, PointCopy.transform.position, 5f * Time.deltaTime);
```

What you are doing is using the `transform` of the `SpawntoLerp` so you will never move farer apart from that position then `5f * Time.deltaTime`.

Instead you want to move on from the current position of `instance`

```
instance.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards
    (instance.transform.position, PointCopy.transform.position, 5f * Time.deltaTime);
```

---

And then you could again use a simple `public Transform` like

```
public class SpawntoLerp : MonoBehaviour
{
    // you can use any Component as field
    // and Unity will automatically take the according reference
    // from the GameObject you drag in
    public Transform CubePrefab;
    public Transform instance;

    // Do not call it transform as this property already exists in MonoBehaviour
    public Transform PointCopy;

    private void Start()
    {
        // instantiate automatically returns the same type
        // as the given prefab
        instance = Instantiate(CubePrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        instance.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(instance.position, PointCopy.position, 5f * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

---

A better solution regarding efficiency would be to use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) instead because you don't want to move anymore once the position is reached anyway:

```
public class SpawntoLerp : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform CubePrefab;
    public Transform PointCopy;

    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SpawnAndMove(CubePrefab, PointCopy.position));
    }

    private IEnumerator SpawnAndMove(GameObject prefab, Vector3 targetPosition)
    {
        Transform instance = Instantiate(CubePrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);

        while(Vector3.Distance(instance.position, targetPosition) > 0)
        {
            instance.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(instance.position, targetPosition, 5f * Time.deltaTime);

            // "Pause" the routine, render this frame and 
            // continue from here in the next frame
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that is super helpful, especially the Coroutine part. That was my next problem to solve, so I'm very grateful for this guide. Thank you.